# Understanding decidability

Tags: turing-machines

Sorry this is a basic question to understand decidability. It is the first time I see it in my undergrad course.

**1)**
I am reading why the language `AFDA` is decidable and why `ATM` (halting problem) is not. The explanation says that the emulated `TM` in `ATM` might loop forever. I agree, because a specific input string might make the `TM` going forever, always able to apply rules and never halting.

However, why is `AFDA` decidable? What if the automaton never reaches any of its final states and keeps looping? There might be a specific input that makes the `FDA` never reach such states. I understand that once the input string finishes, it will be either accepted or rejected, but what if it does not finish? I'm assuming the input string in the `TM` can be infinite.

**2)**
The same problem I have here:

```
A = { 0^k 1^k | k >= 0}
```

This language is decidable, and it will halt in strings like `10`, `010101`, etc but what if the input string is infinite `01010101......` it will never end.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am sorry but I originally published it in StackOverflow where I saw plenty of questions about TMs. Then I was sent here... then now you -1 my question and send me to Computer Science... Nobody agrees. I think my question is strongly related to theoretical computer science, though...

Comment: no dispute that this relates to theoretical computer science. However, it's the "level" of the question that places it in CS.SE. I'm sorry that SO moved you here: they should have moved you straight to CS.SE

Comment: Yes, thanks. I read the help center and I agree the question does not belong here. I did not even know about this site, but this is what I was told in SO... Sorry about that

Comment: too many acronyms around ... I have done quite a bit of automata theory, but I do not recall seeing AFDA before.

Answer (score 2):

1) The automaton "halts" after it reads the input, whether or not it reaches a final state.  It *accepts* the input if, when it halts, it's in a final state.

2) Inputs are always finite strings.  There are generalizations of finite automata ($\omega$-automata of various kinds  [Buchi, Rabin, Muller]) that accept $\omega$-words (countably infinite strings) as inputs.

Comment: Thanks. 2) So I assume that despite k being defined as k >= 0 it is bound to be a natural number (so finite). 1) I think this is solved the same way too - if the input string is finite, then there is no possible infinite "w" and the automaton will certainly halt, correct?

Answer (score 0):

1) I haven’t heard of the “AFDA” acronym before, but I assume you mean the acceptance-problem for [Deterministic Finite Automatons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). In that case, the answer is that the input strings in this machine model are *always finite*. Because the DFA always halts, a Turing machine can decide whether a given DFA accepts the input or not.

2) Again, in all common machine models input strings are *always finite*, especially in undergrad courses where you typically adress finite-state machines, Turing machines, pushdown automata,… (Unless, of course, infinite input strings are explicitly allowed in your specific machine model.)